# GridSplitter resize next

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, gridsplitter

It seems I can't use `GridSplitter` to resize **next** item. Here is xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- this works -->
    <Grid Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="10" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" />
    </Grid>
    <!-- this doesn't -->
    <Grid Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="10" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and demo:

[image]

Notice what left `Grid` can be resized, while right one has some issues. You can try given xaml yourself to see what I mean.

What should I do to make **next** item resizing working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work by changing ColumnDefinition Width

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="10" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="10" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and another variant I like more:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Background="Gray">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="10" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" />

        <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Gold"/>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" Width="10" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Do you have explanation why `*` is working and `auto` is also working but only in one direction? My problem is to have *optional* content in non-resizable column, this is why it must be `auto`. Not sure if it will work with `*`, give me a minute.

Comment: @Sinatr, i can only guess that is inner logic of splitter. Since grids have Left  and Right horizontal alignment, `*` becomes an `auto`